# How do I get from Four Different Exits to the top of Connecting the Pieces?

Tags: antichamber

In *Four Different Exits*, there is an exit to a hallway right above the *Connecting the Pieces* hallway.

[image: Fifth exit]

I tried jumping from a yellow block on top of the larger movable block, but I can't seem to get high enough to reach it.
[image: Yellow block on large cube]

What do I have to do to get up there?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put the yellow block against the bottom railing and stand on it. Select it with the middle click and aim straight up next to the top railing. On the way up or at the top, you should be able to jump the gap.